# If I conquer a Civ do I get their techs?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

Aside from having 1 less enemy what happens if I conquer another Civ, specifically do I get their tech?

Answer (score 5):

No, you won't get a civ's techs automatically, if you conquer it.
You can negotiate some techs "in bundle" with the capitulation/peace treaty deal, but from the conquest itself it doesn't follow that you'll get any techs at all.

Comment: I would agree with this from my own experience but if you could find a source to clarify it would further improve the answer.

Comment: Is there some calculation for how they decide when to give up techs for peace because I had a grand army, and they were down to their last two cities and ended up giving up only one tech for peace

Comment: @MCB, sorry, I must have missed the comment. The calculation definitely is there, but I don't know it. I mean, there are definitely some lines of software code in Python or C++ or whatever, but I haven't looked so deep. Usually, when I'm being at war, I periodically check the diplomatic screen with the enemy and offer him a truce with the "let's bury the hatchet, what is the price for peace" option, and look what he offers me in return.

Comment: @lozzajp, sorry, I must have missed your comment either. I cannot name any source, and Civilopedia doesn't seem to mention this in its War and Victory sections, and it seems that the creators of the game considered this so obvious that it had no need to be mentioned. I destroyed other civs numerous times, and can confirm that there never was any transitions of technologies.